# Not able to update reducer state in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

On change of select I want to save the value in reducer. But How can I pass the value into state.
below is the code I am using.

container/header/index.js

```
const changeCloud = () => {
  return ('hello');
}

const mapStateToProps = () => ({
  cloud: changeCloud(),
  menuItems: menuItems,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCloud: () => {
    dispatch(setCloud('sf'));
  },
})

const Header = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HeaderPresentational);
```

component/header/index.js

```
setCloudClick(evt) {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value,
    }, function () {
      this.props.setCloud('this.state.value');
    });
  }

render(){
    return(
    <select onChange={this.setCloudClick} value={this.state.value}>
        <option value="zscaler.net">zscaler.net</option>
        <option value="zscalerOne.net">zscalerOne.net</option>
        <option value="zscaler.net">ZscalerTwo.net</option>
        <option value="Zscaler Private Access">Zscaler Private Access</option>
    </select>
);
}
```

reducer.js

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_CLOUD' :
      alert(action.text);
      return state;
    default :
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the callback, you need to pass the `value` and not the `string`

```
setCloudClick(evt) {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value,
    }, function () {
      this.props.setCloud(this.state.value);  // pass this.state.value here
    });
  }
```

However, when you are storing value in store, you need not store it locally. You can dispatch the value like

index.js

```
setCloudClick(evt) {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value,
    }, function () {
      this.props.setCloud(this.state.value);
    });
  }

render(){
    return(
         <select onChange={this.setCloudClick} value={this.state.value}>
            <option value="zscaler.net">zscaler.net</option>
            <option value="zscalerOne.net">zscalerOne.net</option>
            <option value="zscaler.net">ZscalerTwo.net</option>
            <option value="Zscaler Private Access">Zscaler Private Access</option>
        </select>
    );
}
```

container/header/index.js

```
const changeCloud = () => {
  return ('hello');
}

const mapStateToProps = () => ({
  cloud: changeCloud(),
  menuItems: menuItems,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCloud: (value) => {
    dispatch(setCloud(value));
  },
})

const Header = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HeaderPresentational);
```

Comment: Yes I am doing that also it is giving undefined.

Comment: @Bhawna, Check the update, also where are you getting undefine

Comment: Glad it helped :)